# Single Group Group Function- Orders and Products

Tags: mysql, sql

I am supposed to list the product ID, product name, and product price for the highest priced product(s).  Format the price as currency, and use the following column headings:  `ProductID, Name, Price`.

I am Receiving a

> not a single-group group function

error

```
 SELECT PR.Product_ID as Prod_ID, PR.Product_Name as Name, to_char(MAX)
 (PR.Product_Price),'$999.99') as Price
 FROM PRODUCT_arb PR;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Then why don't you select exactly that?

```
SELECT product_id, product_name, product_price
FROM product_arb
WHERE product_price = (SELECT MAX(product_price) FROM product_arb)
```

You can reformat the price column as you wish.

Concerning your query, I do not know what that: `to_char(MAX) (PR.Product_Price),'$999.99')` should be. It's not even valid syntax.